# SE Header Fix userscript

Tags: script, tampermonkey

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: screenshot]

### About

This is a userscript to revert Stack Exchange's [recent header bar styling change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377614/1116284). It re-dims the icons and re-formats the little "unread" numbers above the icons.

#### License

This script is 100% open-source and available on my [userscript repo on GitHub](https://github.com/GingerIndustries/userscripts/) under the MIT License.

#### Download

Get it here: https://github.com/GingerIndustries/userscripts/raw/main/SE%20Header%20Fix.user.js

#### Platform

Any browser that supports TamperMonkey/GreaseMonkey will work with this script.

### Contact

You can find me (Ginger) in [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

### Code

This was made with TamperMonkey. If you want to contribute you can do so on [the GitHub](https://github.com/GingerIndustries/userscripts/).

Comment: Anybody who downloaded this prior to this comment needs to reinstall as old versions break voting icons and a few other things

Comment: If you look at [newest post](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script%2b-app?tab=Newest) the image from your post is a bit.. squeezed. You can make a thumbnail yourself. I usually pick a ratio of 4x3. When you have an imgur link, you can add it with `<!-- thumbnail: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxxxx.png -->` at the top of your post :)